# jQuery load("file.php *") difficulty

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to setup a dynamic content loading page but for some reason the following code:

```
$("#area").load('doc.php *');
```

doesn't work for files without any surrounding tags. For example, the following file will show in the content area:

```
<!--doc.php-->
<p>Hello</p>
```

but this won't:

```
<!--doc.php-->
Hello
```

Comment: Remove `*`..I don't see any purpose to it under this context anyway.

Comment: Why the trailing `*`? Why not `$("#area").load('doc.php');`?

Comment: The `*` is a selector, meaning what to get (he want to get everything). So it's useless to have it anyways.

Comment: Solved by Ohgodwhy, thanks!
I'm just new to jQuery which used ".load('doc.php *');" as the way to load everything from a file, didn't know it would work without!